# User input in Batch doesn't work in Windows 8, or am I wrong?

Tags: windows-8, batch

```
@ECHO OFF
CLS

SET ad =
SET /p ad = Do you want to [A] Allow or [D] Deny? 
ECHO "%ad%"
```

I type `A` and press `Enter`, and the output I get is:

```
Do you want to [A] Allow or [D] Deny?
""
```

Why doesn't it work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You aren't setting `%ad%`. You are setting `%ad %`.

Some languages are more picky about whitespace than others. The `cmd.exe` script language is one of them – the syntax for setting a variable is `set name=value`, and if you add spaces around the `=`, they become *part of the variable name and value*.

If you're writing the script for Windows 7/8 only, I strongly recommend learning PowerShell instead. The language used by cmd.exe is *awful*.

Comment: Note that PowerShell also comes with Vista. It's also available as a download for XP (and apparently as a recommended update, though I can't confirm). Note that there are different versions with varying features, though the basic syntax is the same. It's also far more powerful than the legacy command line (it supports .NET as far as any programming language, e.g. C# or VB.NET), though a bit heavier.

Comment: I didn't even know that variables could have spaces! This is the most ridiculous property of a language I've seen until now. I'm actually just using this to change some properties on a server, so I just want it to work as fast as possible..

Comment: @StudentofHogwarts: You still haven't seen some *interesting* properties of PHP, or MUMPS, or FORTRAN...

Comment: @grawity Actually PHP was the first language I learned, and you are completely correct, there is a lot of (please pardon me, but this is actually right from the soul) crap in PHP. So I'm actually considering using Django instead, but I suppose it's more "okay" since that's what I've "grown up with"..

Comment: @StudentofHogwarts: Including `${"variable names that have spaces.\n
\n
And newlines."}`

Comment: @grawity Well, that one I think is a good feature.. Because you have to use this special syntax, and thus you can do very dynamic things. For a seasoned programmer, this shouldn't be good feature, because good programming habits will not need such functionality, but for new programmers this is an easy way to get to their goal as fast as possible. After all,  PHP is made to be extremely easy to make simple scripts, but still include the good programmers. (And one can of course discuss how well they do the latter...)

Comment: @StudentofHogwarts http://xkcd.com/1171 I've seen regular expressions that were a few pages long.

Comment: @MarkAllen Well, that's when you should consider if your application has too much bad code, or if the application is really too slow for production. Good one you got there!

Comment: @StudentofHogwarts The guy who wrote it is a brilliant developer, and the solution worked great. I just wouldn't have done it that way, because calling it unreadable would be a massive understatement.

Comment: @MarkAllen Emm, I think I've skipped out on something here, because to me that didn't make much sense xD

Comment: @StudentofHogwarts It was regarding "regular expressions that were a few pages long".

Answer (score 3):

The command processor in Windows 8 is unchanged from the one in Windows 7, as far as I know

Everything up to the equals sign is part of the variable name. So in this case, your variable name is actually `"ad "` without the quotes. You can view current environment variables with the command `set` without any parameters - this is very useful for debugging.